# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool after upgrading to php 7.4

Tags: php, arrays, php-7.4

I have just upgraded the php version to 7.4.9
And I began receiving this error:

`Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /var/www/html/forms/melagot/api/class/Dashboard.php on line 84`

I understand that the error says that the array is empty, and it is. the thiNg is that when there are values in the array I get the undefined value error.

```
 public function get_student_data($id, $current_year)
    {

   $query = "SELECT * FROM form WHERE `id`=? AND `year` = ?";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $current_year);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->execute();
    
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    $this->is_army_file = $row['is_army_file'];  //this is line 84
    }
```

I have tried placing this in line 84
 `(isset($row['is_army_file']) ? $this->is_army_file = $row['is_army_file'] : false);`
I dont see the erreo but I dont see the `$this->is_army_file` value where it should be, instead I see undefined variable error.

If I leave it as it is I see the error but I also see the value.

I tried `$this->is_army_file =?? $row['is_army_file'];`
But I receive an error as well.
how can fix this?

Comment: It would seem `$row` is actually `false`, because `$stmt->fetch` has failed, perhaps because there is no data matching the parameters?

Comment: Note you have two calls to `$stmt->execute()`, that might cause a problem...

Comment: this functions load in two pages, one where the array is empty and one where it is full
How shoul I write the turnerry  in the page where the array is full?

Comment: You can probably just use `$this->is_army_file = $row ? $row['is_army_file'] : false;`

Comment: Just pointing out a slight difference, right now your code assigns `null` if the query returns no results. (see `var_dump(false['is_army_file']);`) If that is important you might want to change `false` to `null` in your else case.

Comment: @Nick Thank you, just ded as you suggested and it works fine
Thanks